# How to display JsonObject in addOnItemTouchListener

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I want display **info and file** object when clicking item in Recyclerview I am using volley and `JsonObject` request but can not display **info and file**. When I use toast for **zakeran_any_madah** display unclear, how to resolve my problem and display **info and file** for correct position، Is there any other way?

This is my code

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            res = String.valueOf(response);
            Log.d("reres", res);
            datajson = response;


            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                    int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                    int id_category = jsonObject.getInt("id_category");
                    int id_speaker = jsonObject.getInt("id_speaker");
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                    String category_name = jsonObject.getString("category_name");
                    String speaker_name = jsonObject.getString("speaker_name");
                    JSONArray ja = jsonObject.getJSONArray("files");
                    for (int j = 0; j < ja.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(j);
                        file = jo.getString("file");
                        info = jo.getString("info");
                        Item_zakerin_any itemzakeran = new Item_zakerin_any(id, id_category, name, id_speaker, image, speaker_name, category_name, info, file);
                        list_zakeran_any.add(itemzakeran);

                    }


                }
                az = new adapter_zakeran_any(mcontext, list_zakeran_any);

                rv.setAdapter(az);
                hidepDialog();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                hidepDialog();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {




            hidepDialog();
        }
    });


    jsonObjectr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectr);



    rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

        GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(zakeran_any_madah.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                return true;
            }

        });
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            ChildView =rv.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
            if (ChildView !=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){
                GetItemPosition =rv.getChildAdapterPosition(ChildView);
                Toast.makeText(zakeran_any_madah.this, ""+ list_zakeran_any.get(GetItemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




            }



            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If you have any error-code or error-log.. paste that into your question. This refines the help.

Comment: @ZF007 I have no error but I do not know how to display josnobject file and info

Comment: If you tried something but failed that should throw errorcode. I'm not familiar with java as such so I can't help on that. I had your question for review because there are some parts missing. That is what I try to clear-up a little. GL with getting help and useful answer. BTW.. finish the tour ;-)

Comment: add you JSON response